# How to simulate a key press for 5 seconds on the keyboard using TestCafe

Tags: typescript, keyboard, e2e-testing, testcafe, automation-testing

I tried to send it to the browser console by pressing `.pressKey("PageDown")`, after tracking it, but nothing came of it. Who can tell what steps to take next, maybe there are examples? I was told that you can use the `clientfunction`, but I can’t understand how to put it all together due to the lack of the same examples. The attempted code is below:

```
    await t
       .click(S(sCounter))
       .pressKey("PageDown");
    await t.eval(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        console.log(event.key);

        if (event.key === "PageDown") {
            console.log("PageDown press");
            let isKeyPressed = false;
            let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null = null;
            isKeyPressed = true;
            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                isKeyPressed = false;
                if (timeoutId !== null) {
                    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                }
            }, 10 * 1000); // set the timeout to the specified number of seconds
        }
        console.log("PageDown Up");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The t.pressKey action simulates a sequence of "keydown", "keypress", and "keyup" events. To simulate holding a key, you can use the [t.dispatchEvent](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403091/reference/test-api/testcontroller/dispatchevent) action. Here is an example of its usage: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1839#issuecomment-1506640783.

Also, according to your code snippet, you need to add an event listener before the action occurs. Place the `t.eval` call above `click` and `pressKey`.